# Adding up a column but ignoring duplicates

Tags: r, sum

I need to add up one column of data to find how many people there are, however, every person has 5 or more entries. How do I add up everyone once and ignore duplicates of the same person. 
Sorry if it's a silly question, just getting started on R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
> x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
> sum(x[!duplicated(x)])
[1] 6
```

or more like this?

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), value = rnorm(6))
sum(df$value[!duplicated(df$id)])
```

Comment: no sorry I should have been clearer, its a list of ID numbers, and I don't want to actually add them, just want to know how many there are. if I use sum() it counts all of the duplicates so im left with a figure much higher than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

so, more like this

```r
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
length(x[!duplicated(x)])
[1] 3
```

Comment: Indeed, when it's just counting and not summing as I initially thought that is definitely more elegant - and in fact `sum(unique(x))` should also work for summing.